# Can some guide me on Carnet De Passages

Tags: visas, international-travel, driving

I wish to Travel from India to Singapore by my 4 Wheel and i will be crossing the Border of Myanmar, Thailand, Malaysia and will be reaching my final destination Singapore.

So in this route which country needs Carnet De Passages and if some can advice me that would be highly appreciated.